# Django count queryset, show object instead of PK

Tags: python, django

I wrote a query to sort a count count query for biggest to smallest number. Basically a ranking system.

```
    users = Referrals.objects.values('friend_id').annotate(Count('friend_id')).order_by('-friend_id__count')
```

It returns the value in json format like this

```
<QuerySet [{'friend_id': 1, 'friend_id__count': 2}, {'friend_id': 5, 'friend_id__count': 1}]>
```

now friend_id appears to be the primary key and yes, it links to the correct one(s) in my DB.. but I have no idea to get it to let it output the actual name / email or whatever based on that PK?

This is my template where I'd like it to display the rankings.

```
                  {% for a in users %}
                  <tr>
                      <td>{{a}}</td>
                      <td>{{a}}</td>
                  </tr>

                  {% endfor %}
```

Here's my full view for what its worth.

```
@login_required
def statspage(request):
    users = Referrals.objects.values('friend_id').annotate(Count('friend_id')).order_by('-friend_id__count')
    print(users)

    context = {
        'users': users,
    }

    return render(request, 'stats.html', context)
```

One more question - is it possible to filter based on a boolean that exists in the User model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `friend` is a FK to `User` model that has fields named `email` and `first_name` (and `last_name`), you can specify those fields in the `.values(...)` part as follows:

```
Referrals.objects.values('friend_id', 'friend__email', 'friend__first_name') ...
```

Comment: One more question - is it possible to filter based on a boolean that exists in the User model?

Comment: @RonaldLangeveld Have you tried filtering like `Referrals.objects.values(...).filter(friend__boolfield=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
users = Referrals.objects.all().annotate(
    friend_count=Count('friend_id')
).order_by('-friend_count')
```

When you use `values` it will only return the db column which you specified.

In the template you can access like

```
{% for user in users %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.friend_count}}</td>
      </tr>

 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am not sure but `Referrals` is tied to `User` model with a foreign key called `friend` so `Referrals.objects.all()` probably doesn't populate any fields in the `User` table. You need to explicitly ask for field values from another model using `model__foo` lookup.

Comment: what you are not sure @ozgur